# ie 7 defineProperty forEach es5-shim

Tags: internet-explorer

Подскажите есть ли в 2020 какая-то пилюля в виде одной библиотеки?
Есть какой-то Modernizr, но я ни чего не понял как это дабро интегрировать?!

Лет 5-7 назад, мне надо было тоже подобным заниматься, но там только в плане CSS
CSS в текущем проекте тоже буду делать, но после JS, сперва этот недуг победить

Раньше я PIE какой-то использовал, разгуглю
Но если что-то поменялось, укажите на это

Спасибо